# Possible to use List/Dictionary Comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

so I was going through this exercise and I was wondering if there is a way of writing this out using comprehensions. Also how do I get this popup about me not adding enough info to let me post my code lol

Thanks in advance!

```
    lloyd = {
        "name": "Lloyd",
        "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
        "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
        "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    }
    alice = {
        "name": "Alice",
        "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
        "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
        "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    }
    tyler = {
        "name": "Tyler",
        "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
        "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
        "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    }


    # Add your function below!
    def average(numbers):
        total = float(sum(numbers)) / len(numbers)
        return total


    student = [lloyd, alice, tyler]


    def get_average(student):
        homework = average(student["homework"]) * .10
        quizzes = average(student["quizzes"]) * .30
        tests = average(student["tests"]) * .60
        return homework + tests + quizzes


    def get_letter_grade(score):
        if score >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif score >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif score >= 70:
            return "C"
        elif score >= 60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"


    print(get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd)))


    def get_class_average(students):
        results = []
        for student in students:
            results.append(get_average(student))
        return average(results)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. I had it somewhat close to yours! I was missing the average and ()

Answer (score 0):

The `get_class_average function` can be modified to:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results = average([get_average(student) for student in students])
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the average of scores for each student,
you can use dict comprehension as follows,

```
average_new = {ind['name']:sum(float(sum(ind[key]))/len(ind[key]) for key in ind if not isinstance(ind[key],str))/3 for ind in student}
grades = {90:'A',80:'B',70:'C',60:'D',0:'F'}

name='lloyd'
grade = grades[sorted(filter(lambda g:average_new[name.title()]>=g,grades))[-1]]
print grade
```

Breaking down the code,

1 To get the individual student information for student list.

```
>>> print [ind for ind in student]
[{'quizzes': [88.0, 40.0, 94.0], 'tests': [75.0, 90.0], 'name': 'Lloyd', 'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]}, {'quizzes': [82.0, 83.0, 91.0], 'tests': [89.0, 97.0], 'name': 'Alice', 'homework': [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0]}, {'quizzes': [0.0, 75.0, 78.0], 'tests': [100.0, 100.0], 'name': 'Tyler', 'homework': [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]}]
```

2 get all keys for every indivialy information

```
>>> print [[key  for key in ind] for ind in student]
[['quizzes', 'tests', 'name', 'homework'], ['quizzes', 'tests', 'name', 'homework'], ['quizzes', 'tests', 'name', 'homework']]
```

3 get all key that doesnt hold a string value

```
>>> print [[key  for key in ind if not isinstance(ind[key],str)] for ind in student]
[['quizzes', 'tests', 'homework'], ['quizzes', 'tests', 'homework'], ['quizzes', 'tests', 'homework']]
```

4 find value for all keys that isnt a string for every individual

```
>>> print [[float(sum(ind[key]))/len(ind[key]) for key in ind if not isinstance(ind[key],str)] for ind in student]
[[74.0, 82.5, 88.5], [85.33333333333333, 93.0, 97.5], [51.0, 100.0, 46.0]]
```

5 find sum of all values for all keys that isnt a string for every individual

```
>>> print [sum(float(sum(ind[key]))/len(ind[key]) for key in ind if not isinstance(ind[key],str)) for ind in student]
[245.0, 275.8333333333333, 197.0]
```

6 find average of all keys that isnt a string for every individual

```
>>> print [sum(float(sum(ind[key]))/len(ind[key]) for key in ind if not isinstance(ind[key],str))/3 for ind in student]
[81.66666666666667, 91.94444444444444, 65.66666666666667]
```

7 map the result with the student name

```
>>> print {ind['name']:sum(float(sum(ind[key]))/len(ind[key]) for key in ind if not isinstance(ind[key],str))/3 for ind in student}
{'Tyler': 65.66666666666667, 'Lloyd': 81.66666666666667, 'Alice': 91.94444444444444}
```

And you the filter the result to get the grade!